# Партиционирование по не известному заранее списку (Oracle)

Tags: база-данных, oracle

Добрый день.

Разбираюсь с партиционированием в Оракле. Во всех примерах, которые я нагуглил, для партиционирования по списку список известен заранее и явно указывается при описании партиций.

Я же хочу, чтобы для каждого значения определённого столбца всегда была отдельная партиция. При этом пока не известен полный список возможных значений (известно только, что их будет относительно немного).

При этом хочется, чтобы если в таблицу добавляется запись с новым значением в этом столбце, то под неё бы сразу автоматически заводилась отдельная партиция.

Есть ли способ сделать такое?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, в 12.2

> Partitioning: Auto-List Partitioning
>   The database automatically creates a separate (new) partition for every distinct partition key value of the table.
>
> Auto-list partitioning removes the management burden from the DBAs to manually maintain a list of partitioned tables for a large number of distinct key values that require individual partitions. It also automatically copes with the unplanned partition key values without the need of a DEFAULT partition.

Comment: То есть я правильно понял, что при создании таблицы мне нужно после собственно описания таблицы просто добавить строчку PARTITION BY LIST (column_name) и этого будет достаточно?

Comment: Я синтаксиса не знаю, смотрите документацию.

Comment: @Александр вам же нужно автоматом, так и напишите: `partition by list (column) automatic`, укажите какую нибудь одну партицию и default не надо.